# JSON giving me wrong json message

Tags: php, json, react-native

If there anything not clear in this post, I am ready to answer it but please help me to solve it.I tried to remove '()' from response.json and This is  [JSON MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDIk1.png) occured when i did this. When i add  response.json() it will give me unexpected token '<'

and this is react-native fetch

```
fetch('url',{
        method:'post',
        header:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
            // we will pass our input data to server
            username: userEmail,
            password: userPassword
        })

    })
    .then((response) => response.json)
     .then((responseJson)=>{
         if(responseJson == "ok"){
             // redirect to profile page
             alert("Successfully Login");
             this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
         }else{
             alert(responseJson);
         }
     })
     .catch((error)=>{
     console.error(error);
     });
```

PHP file :

```
 include 'config.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');   
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$username = $obj['username'];

$password = $obj['password'];

if($obj['username']!=""){   

    $check_user="SELECT * FROM logintest where username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result= mysqli_query($con,$check_user);




    if($result->num_rows==0){

          $MSG = 'Wrong Details' ;


          $json = json_encode($MSG);


               echo $json ;         
    }
```

Can someone please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Ah, the one problem with `fetch()` where the error message aren't exactly helpful. `response.json` is a function that parses your response data into JSON, as you've read in that box. Before anything, what does your `echo $json` output? Have you tested this with Postman or anything? The unexpected token '<' error just means your response data is not JSON so you need to check the data that your php responds with.

Comment: No i didn't tested with Postman and i don't know what are you talking about.My PhP file is above. echo $json should output this message ('Wrong Details')

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I suggest you test your PHP route with Postman first and let us know what your PHP outputs.

Comment: I didn't understand . what you want me to explain for you ?

Comment: You should use https://www.getpostman.com/ to check what output result really is and provide it in your question

Comment: I want you to explain what your PHP actually outputs, by using the application named Postman. Because, unexpected token '<' is very likely caused by your PHP responding with HTML (which also starts with '<').

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to use it. and i see it a complicated platform. all my app is about login page using php and mysql as a backend